# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I'm using tomcat for running my webapplication. I'm trying to integrate keycloak through spring security adapter. 
 
Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only spring-security-adapter dependency in pom.xml.Add tomcat adapter jars inside lib folder of tomcat.Because of adding two dependencies inside pom conflict araising while loading the classes